# How to access the dom by knowing the value of a node && Getting the index of accordion by just knowing value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, accordion

I have 2 questions:

1) Since I have similar structure for the html contents and the only difference is that class title contents are different. I tried using $(div .title:contains("cat")) also 
$(div .title).text()="cat")

2)How can I get the index of the accordion by just checking  the $(div a) contents are required ones. I tried using $(div a).text()=="cat"

Check the codes here:

HTML1 contents

```
    <div class="mod moduleselected" id="mod969">
    <div class="content module moduleselect">
    <div class="hd" ><div class="inner">
    <div class="title">cat</div>
    <ul class="terminallist"></ul>
    <ul class="buttons">
    <li class="help"></li>
    <li class="show" ></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mod moduleselected" id="mod969">
    <div class="content module moduleselect">
    <div class="hd" ><div class="inner">
    <div class="title">rat</div>
    <ul class="terminallist"></ul>
    <ul class="buttons">
    <li class="help"></li>
    <li class="show" ></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

<div class="mod moduleselected" id="mod969">
    <div class="content module moduleselect">
    <div class="hd" ><div class="inner">
    <div class="title">dog</div>
    <ul class="terminallist"></ul>
    <ul class="buttons">
    <li class="help"></li>
    <li class="show" ></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Accordian

```
        <div id="dia">
        <div id="dialog" title="Detailed FeedBack ">
        <div id="accordion">
        <h3><a href="#">dog</a></h3>
        <h3><a href="#">cat</a></h3>
        <h3><a href="#">rat</a></h3>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Javascript

```
        $('div .title').mouseover(function() {
    if($("div a").text().indexOf("cat")!=-1)
    {
    $("#accordion").accordion("activate", 1);
    }
    $('div .title').mouseleave(function(){$("#accordion").accordion("activate", -1); });
        });
```

Here is what I am trying to do with this javascript code. When I mouse over the cat contents I want the accordion with cat contents to open. And when I leave it to close the accordion selection.

When I hover my mouse over the html contents cat ,rat. It should side by side open the accordion button of those contents. Example: I hovered over rat (of html contents) I should see accordion rat open (or active i.e. contents visible).

Comment: Note that html element IDs *must be unique* (only one can have `id='mod969'`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Updated (see demo)**](http://jsfiddle.net/hKunn/)

It sounds like you want something like this: when a content section is hovered over, find the title of that section, match its text against the text of the `<a>` elements in the accordion, and activate that section:

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion();

    var links = $('#accordion a').map(function() {
        return $(this).text().trim().toLowerCase();
    }).toArray();

    $('div.content').mouseover(function() {
        var title = $(this).find('div.title').text().toLowerCase();
        var index = links.indexOf(title);
        if (index != -1) {
            $("#accordion").accordion("activate", index);
        }
    });
});​
```

P.S. jQuery does have a [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method for this as well.

Comment: Can you suggest what will happen using $('div.content') since to my understanding it will select contents inside the div. But since there are multiple divs how can it just select the one with Sample2. The only difference is the contents of title class.

Comment: `content` is your class name; `div.content` selects the div with class name 'content'. I don't know how your full html looks, you can post the full code in a jsfiddle. This should work for all of the samples, not just sample 2. Are you getting an error?

Comment: HTML1 shows how the contents will look like. I was trying $(.title) or $(div.title).text() but the text is null for both cases. T

Comment: You need to wrap those in quotes: `$(".title")` or `$("div.title").text()`

Comment: Sorry actually I used the quotes also

Comment: @judy This works fine for me (I was missing a `$` in one line but I don't think that was your prob...). I've updated and included a demo. The problem you are noticing arose because your accordion wasn't complete -- under each `<h3>` you need a `<div>` containing the content to show when that section is active. Please see my demo, including the updated html.

Answer (score 1):

It should be as succinct as the following (with potential minor tweaks):

```
$('.content .title').hover(function(e){
    var index = this.textContent.split(/\W/)[1] - 1;    
    $("#accordion").accordion('activate', index);
});
​
```

Be careful with the HTML as this regular expression is overly simple in that it just grabs the last "word" which in the case of your example is a number. We subtract one to get a zero-based index. That will break if you add further text to the element.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/35yGV/

Comment: @ wilmoore: Thanks a lot.Actually the contents of the title are text in my case and not numbers in the end so I should be fine. Actually I think my question is not clear. When I hover my mouse over the html contents sample 1 ,sample 2. It should side by side open the accordion button of those contents. Example: I hovered over sample2 (of html contents) I should see accordion sample 2 open (or active i.e. contents visible). Please can you suggest how to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: What I provided is supposed to do what you are asking. If it is not, then perhaps there is some detail I am missing. What is the result when you try this. Do you see an error message in the console? Is anything opening? Do you have the jQuery accordion plugin loaded correctly? Can you trigger the accordion to open manually by calling .accordion('activate', hard-coded-number-here)?

Comment: Yes everything is working file. But when i take the mouse over accordion it shows me tooltip with feedback written there. Is this  what the code was written for? Its not giving the index of the accordion when I am going to the html contents